# Why won't a Wagtail TableBlock Display Properly in the Admin?

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield, wagtail-admin

I'd like to have a `TableBlock` display in my admin panel, but it isn't displaying properly.

Here are the errors I'm getting:
[image: JavaScript Console]

And here's the code block:

```py
from wagtail.contrib.table_block.blocks import TableBlock
from wagtail.core.blocks import StreamBlock
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField

class BaseStreamBlock(StreamBlock):
    table = TableBlock()


class ArticlePage(Page):
    parent_page_types = ['home.HomePage']
    subpage_types = []

    content = StreamField(BaseStreamBlock(), verbose_name=_('Content'), blank=True)

    content_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('title'),
        ]),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                StreamFieldPanel('content'),
            ]
        ),
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you remember to add `"wagtail.contrib.table_block"` to INSTALLED_APPS, as per https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/table_block.html#installation ?

Comment: Yes I add it to INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the browser console (in developer tools)?

Comment: Thank you for idia, I don't resolve the probleb but find error at console

Comment: I attach picture of error to post above, Look like I have problems with backet access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors in the browser console show that the Javascript files included in the `wagtail.contrib.table_block` app are not loading. Most likely, these are missing from your S3 file hosting (S3 returns 403 Forbidden for missing files).

After adding `wagtail.contrib.table_block` to INSTALLED_APPS and deploying to your server, you'll need to re-run `./manage.py collectstatic` to ensure these JS files are uploaded to S3.